# Epson projector

Tags: linux, epson, projector

I have a projector that can accept control commands like turn on/off and queries like amount of time it was on.

Control commands work, but I can't seem to capture responses from queries; when I connect via USB, I get two additional raw input files in the dev directory.

I wrote a C program that captures events from input devices it captures mouse movements and keyboard events, but it doesn't capture replies from the projector at all, not even the event itself. Why is that?

In Windows, everything works.

Comment: It's not clear what question you're asking

Comment: When I send a command thru serial to the projector the projector is supposed to reply via /dev/hidraw2 and I cant capture the reply

Comment: Do you see nothing on /dev/hidraw2, or just not what you expect? Can you open /dev/hidraw2, what are the permissions? On my machine I see a /dev/hidraw0 with permissions 600, so a normal user would not be able to open it.

Comment: I get nothing using sudo